# What is the purpose of Marshal and what is the difference between Marshal and Famous question?

Tags: discussion

On [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/badges/72/marshal) page, I see a same icon which I see in my GDSE profile. I have 1 badge with that icon.

[image]

My profile:

[image]

But the one in my profile is I think Famous question badge. So what is this Marshal thing? Is it also a badge? If yes, why it has same icon? And what privileges you get with Marshal?

Answer (score 1):

Marshal is one of the 6 gold badges that are in the moderation section. But 2 of those badges are only awarded to moderators, of which one can no longer be awarded to anybody on account that the site has graduated. This leaves:

- Marshall
- Steward
- Copy Editor
- Electorate

These are also all special badges that [count towards election candidate scores](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289501/how-is-candidate-score-calculated) show in election. Of these the Marshall and Copy Editor take the most work to attain.

Marshall is also now considerably harder to get since spam filters are much smarter so there is less opportunities for reporting than it used to be. Making Marshall nearly as hard to attain as Copy Editor today. To show how hard it has taken almost exactly a year to attain the last 100 accepted flags.

Personally this then means that after Marshall I am missing

- Copy Editor (11 awarded)
- Refiner (9 awarded)

from a perfect candidate score. Not that i am currently thinking on running for moderation but still one has to have goals in life.

Comment: What is a graduated account?

Comment: When a site moves from beta to "normal" it is considered to have graduated.